# display div using id after click change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck and need a little help. New to jQuery.

Trying to show a div with a certain ID.. but the id will change based on the buttons clicked.

---

what I am trying to accomplish..

- firstoption1 with secondoption1 will display something
- firstoption1 with secondoption2 will display something
- firstoption1 with secondoption3 will display something
- firstoption2 with secondoption1 will display something
- firstoption2 with secondoption2 will display something
- firstoption2 with secondoption3 will display something

now I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated! I have posted my code here, but if you need anything else please let me know..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selectedFirstOption = "firstoption1";
  var selectedSecondOption = "secondoption1";

  $(".optionsSets").hide();

  $(".firstOptionButton").click(function() {
    selectedFirstOption = $(this).attr('id');
   $(".results").html("#" + selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption);
  });

  $(".secondOptionButton").click(function() {
    selectedSecondOption = $(this).attr('id');
   $(".results").html("#" + selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption);
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button id="firstoption1" class="firstOptionButton">First Option 1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="firstoption2" class="firstOptionButton">First Option 2</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button id="secondoption1" class="secondOptionButton">Second Option 1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="secondoption2" class="secondOptionButton">Second Option 2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="secondoption3" class="secondOptionButton">Second Option 3</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="firstoption1secondoption1" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 1</p>
</div>
<div id="firstoption1secondoption2" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 2</p>
</div>
<div id="firstoption1secondoption3" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 3</p>
</div>
<div id="firstoption2secondoption1" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 2 + Second Option 1</p>
</div>
<div id="firstoption2secondoption2" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 1</p>
</div>
<div id="firstoption2secondoption3" class="optionsSets">
  <p>Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 1</p>
</div>

<div class="results">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using simple string concatenation.

```
var selectedID = selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption;
$("#" + selectedID).show();
```

If we imagine that `selectedFirstOption === "firstoption1"` and `selectedSecondOption === "secondoption3"` then

```
selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption
```

is the same thing as

```
"firstoption1" + "secondoption3"
```

Which is also the same thing as

```
"firstoption1secondoption3"
```

Finally, by doing `"#" + selectedID` we produce

```
"#firstoption1secondoption3"
```

which is the selector you're looking for.

Comment: @Wowsk Good catch! Fixed it.

Comment: but how would that work with the the changing of the buttons? option 1 and option 2  will change once a button is clicked...

Comment: @ToniDavisJ Your code doesn't show you changing the options at all. Unless you mean that you change `selectedFirstOption` and `selectedSecondOption`. If that's what you mean then it still works the same. You're already updating the values so you just need to run this code anytime you want to show something i.e. run this at the end of both of your "click" functions.

Comment: yes.. the value of selectedfirstoption and selectedsecondoption will change once a button is clicked.. [link](http://cloudninjas.com/dell-parts/dell-server-memory-upgrades/dell-rackmount-server-memory/dell-poweredge-r710-server-memory-upgrades.html) this is the live project I am working on.. I messed this op because I used tabs instead of buttons.. what is displayed will depend on the highlighted speed and GB

Comment: @ToniDavisJ Right, so this code still works. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Every time you change `selectedFirstOption` or `selectedSecondOption`, just run this code again.

Comment: @MikeC well maybe im confused.. https://jsfiddle.net/v5oy1gru/ is the j fid space I am working on.. hope you can see it.. if I put var selectedID = selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption;
$("#" + selectedID).show(); inside of my click functions that doesnt work.. and if I use that code after my click functions it doesnt do anything.. Sorry if I am confusing you. lol! I just want the div that displays to be based on what two buttons are active

Comment: @ToniDavisJ Oh, I see what you're saying now. Two problems: first, you need to hide all of the `.optionsSets` again before showing just the one you want. Next, you had a typo in some of your HTML which made it look like it wasn't showing the right ones. [Here's your code with those fixes in place.](https://jsfiddle.net/k7zopcah/1/)

Comment: @MikeC Thanks a ton. one little problem.. the second line is exactly what I would like for it to show.. for example.. click the button second option 3 it will say "Showing: First Option 1 + Second Option 3

#firstoption1secondoption3" which is correct.. BUT click first option 2.. it will say "Showing: First Option 2 + Second Option 1

#firstoption2secondoption3" which isnt correct.. it should say Showing: First Option 2 (_what has been changed_) + Second Option 3 (_same one as we selected in the first click_)

#firstoption2secondoption3

Comment: never mind! I fixed it!! thanks @MikeC! I would have been working on that for months!!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some variables to hold states in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selectedFirstOption = "";
  var selectedSecondOption = "";

  $(".optionsSets").hide();

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function (event) {
        $(".optionsSets").hide();

        var btn = $(event.target);
        if (btn.is('.firstOptionButton') {
            selectedFirstOption = btn.get(0).id;
        } else if (btn.is('.secondOptionButton') {
            selectedSecondOption = btn.get(0).id;
        }

        $('#' + selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption).show();
         $(".results").html("#" + selectedFirstOption + selectedSecondOption);
  });
});
```

the show line will always execute, but the jquery result set will be empty until you select both a first option and a second option, meaning nothing will happen.

Comment: This would definitely work but there's no reason to change how the ID's are collected or put the click handler on the document while listening for buttons. I do like the idea of making one click handler though, which you could do with `$(".firstOptionButton, .secondOptionButton")`.

Comment: It's clearly a partial example.  It's up to the OP to shuffle things around to better suit his actual use case.

Comment: Using a delegate on a higher container would also be better if the options are dynamic.  You could add/remove options without managing click handlers.